# Get SELinux permisison list associated with socket base

Tags: selinux, socket

This shows the permissions associated with the `tcp_socket` class:

```
> seinfo -c tcp_socket -x

Classes: 1
   class tcp_socket
inherits socket
{
        connectto
        name_connect
        node_bind
        newconn
        acceptfrom
}
```

But drilling down is not so useful:

```
seinfo -c socket -x

Classes: 1
   class socket
inherits socket
```

I'm aware of [this](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_ObjectClassesPermissions#Common_Socket_Permissions) and that I can dig through reference policy sources and hopefully find the canonical answer, but the former is "now somewhat historical" ("a list ... from the Fedora F-20 policy sources") and the latter is somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief perusal of `man seinfo` hints at the distinction between an actual object class and a "common permission set".

> -c [CLASS], --class [CLASS]
>                 Print  a  list  of object classes or, if CLASS is provided, print **the named object class.**  With -x, print a list of permissions for each displayed object
>                 class.
>
> [...]
>
> --common [COMMON]
>                 Print a list of common permission sets or, if COMMON is provided, print **the named common.**  With -x, print a list of permissions in the set.

And lo:

```
> seinfo --common socket -x

Commons: 1
   common socket
{
        recv_msg
        append
        relabelfrom
        ioctl
        getattr
        lock
        recvfrom
        relabelto
        shutdown
        setattr
        write
        bind
        name_bind
        accept
        getopt
        create
        setopt
        map
        connect
        send_msg
        listen
        read
        sendto
}
```